# Java wrap server ssh tunnel

Tags: java, ssh

I have a simple server Java app that listens on a port, processes commands and replies. 
I would like to make it behave like an ssh server, so that clients connect as if by ssh and all comms are forwarded to my app. This sounds like it could easily be done via ssh port forwarding, but my attempts have failed.

Comment: It's extremely simple, but it's a question about how to operate SSH, not about Java or servers or programming.

Comment: ok, do you know how to do it then ?

Answer (score 0):

The client of your app would do:

```
> ssh -L1234:localhost:1234 your.host.com
```

Where 1234 is the port you are listening on. Then clients' connecting to localhost:1234 will be forwarded to your app via SSH

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to configure the forwarding on the server side, so clients connect the regular way ?